# Search specific site collection in SharePoint search 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, enterprise-search

In my SharePoint 2013 environment I have configured Search service and I have following questions:

1- I need to search only one site collection but the default content source searched the entire web application consisting of all other site collections.How can I restrict it to one site collection only as it is taking lots of disk space as well and its not required.

- I have checked some blogs and they mention about using 'result source' and use it within the page. But I need the crawling to be restricted to just one site . Is it also possible with Result source.

2- I have a document library and it has folders, when I try to search the files inside the folders, I dont get any results even after full crawl. So Is there something to search within the folders that I need to configure.

Please suggest something and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For crawling only one site collection, you can do it in 2 ways

1. **Crawl Rules** : You can create a crawl rule in your Search Service Application, to exclude all the site collection (ex: http://webapp/*). And add a crawl rule to include your site collection.
2. **Content Sources** : Create a content source with the crawl setting option set to 'Only the SharePoint site of each start address' and provide only your site collection url.

Results Sources allow you get the search results from a defined set of items, while the above 2 options will restrict the crawl itself, which reduces the index size.

For your second question, documents from your doc library (including sub folders) should be available in search results. If they are not availalbe, you can check the following
1. Check if they are excluded from search results (from Library Settings)
2. Check the crawl log, to see of these items are crawled successfully

Comment: thank u very much, can we restrict it to search just one library. I tried including the library URL but it does search the whole site collection. Is it possible to do with crawl rules to exclude all other libraries and search just one.

Comment: Yes. For crawling only one document library, you have to use Crawl Rules.
You can create an exclude rule to exclude all (*).
And create an include rule (specify the url of your document library).

Content Source, will crawl the entire site collection, not just the document library.